# I have the code working to get the cost, but how would I re write this to get the name?

Tags: java

I am outputting this to a file sort of like a receipt, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to rewrite the cost to include names with it.

```
    public double getToppingCost()
    {

        double toppingCost = 0.0;


        if (creamCheese.isSelected())
            toppingCost += CREAM_CHEESE;
        if (butter.isSelected())
            toppingCost += BUTTER;
        if (peachJelly.isSelected())
            toppingCost += PEACH_JELLY;
        if (blueberryJam.isSelected())
            toppingCost += BLUEBERRY_JAM;
        if (nutella.isSelected())
            toppingCost += NUTELLA;


        return toppingCost;
     }
```

EDIT: Here are my declarations. I need to write the method so that I can output the names and only the names to a separate file, kind of like a receipt.

```
           public final double CREAM_CHEESE = 0.50;
           public final double BUTTER = 0.25;
           public final double PEACH_JELLY = 0.75;
           public final double BLUEBERRY_JAM = 0.75;
           public final double NUTELLA = 0.50;

           public final String CHEESE = "Cream Cheese";
           public final String BUT = "Butter";
           public final String JELLY = "Peach Jelly";
           public final String JAM = "Blueberry Jam";
           public final String NUT = "Nutella";
```

Comment: What you could do is put all the toppings and their prices in an array, and loop through that.

Comment: take a look at the decorator design pattern https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j40kRwSm4VE

Comment: What do you mean by "include the names with it". All you're outputting is a double. I assume BUTTER is a double value.

Comment: Yeah, butter is a double, I want it in a separate method, but if i copy the code that gets the cost and paste it in a new method and just change the necessary things to make it output names, it only lets the user select one topping. I need it to allow them to select multiple toppings.

Comment: Could you add an example which shows the output you expect with the names in it?

Comment: tomse,

It is difficult to answer that question, mainly because it is outputting to a file. I have the declaration statements.

Comment: OK, so how does the content of the file looks like?

Comment: So the program lets the user choose one bagel, any number of toppings and a coffee, and I need to print out the name of everything they select. So if they select no toppings, nothing will print. If the select every topping This will print "Cream Cheese, Butter, Peach Jelly, Blueberry Jam, Nutella" Or any variation of that.

Comment: If I understand you right you want a method which returns a list of toppings? Than your method which determines the names should return a `List<String>` created e.g. with `new ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: Would that work with the toppings that the user selects?

Comment: If you want the names only - yes. You can check out the API of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to figure out if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
toppings.getSelected().stream()
            .map(t -> t.getName() + " - " + t.getPrice())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```